# horizontal shift of sub- and superscript for \chi

Tags: symbols, subscripts, greek, superscripts, stacking-symbols

I get a small horizontal displacement of sub- and superscript when using the letter \chi. It does not seem to appear for other letters. Does anybody know how to fix this?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[charter,expert]{mathdesign}
\usepackage[scaled=.96]{XCharter}
\begin{document}
$\chi_{0}^{0}$ $\nu_{0}^{0}$ $\mu_{0}^{0}$ $u_{0}^{0}$ $\mathrm{u}_{0}^{0}$
\end{document}
```

output:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The chi is slanted and has in the tfm an italic value:

```
(CHARACTER O 37
   (CHARWD R 0.562)
   (CHARHT R 0.4835)
   (CHARDP R 0.219)
   (CHARIC R 0.051) %<-----
   )
```

This is taken into account by TeX when placing the sub/superscripts.

You can suppress it, but I don't think that this improve the look:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[charter,expert]{mathdesign}
\usepackage[scaled=.96]{XCharter}
\begin{document}
$\chi_{0}^{0}$ $\chi{}_{0}^{0}$ $\chi{\vphantom{\chi}}_{0}^{0}$ 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Note that `\vphantom` is implemented through `\mathchoice`, and that a “4-way-choice node”, being not an atom, cannot carry super-/subscripts.  Indeed, you can check with `\showlists` that an empty atom is inserted after the phantom, and that the super-/subscripts are appended to this empty atom.  This means that the result is the same as if you had said `$\chi{}_{0}^{0}$`.  If you want the phantom to be effective, say $\chi{\vphantom{\chi}}_{0}^{0}$`.

Comment: @GuM ah, yes, not quite sure why I thought an empty atom doesn't work either.